# Find sufficient condition for having $f(x)>0$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, solution-verification, mean-value-theorem

I have to find a sufficient condition for $f(0)$ for having $f(x)>0$, if $f:[0,3]\to\mathbb{R}$ continuous and differentiable, and $f'(x)>-1$ for $x\in(0,3)$.

Since $f$ is differentiable in (0,3) if I apply MVT I have that $\exists c\in(0,x)$ with $0<x<3$ such that $f'(c)=\frac{1}{x}(f(x)-f(0))$. So:
$$f(x)-f(0)>xf'(c)>-x\Longrightarrow f(x)>f(0)-x$$
So a sufficient condition for having $f(x)>0$ is: $f(0)>x>3\Longrightarrow f(0)>0$

Am I right?

Comment: This seems an odd question. A sufficient condition for $f(x)>0$ is, say, $f(x)=17$.

Comment: is not right to say $f(0)>x$? The sufficiet condition must regard f(0) sorry!!!

Comment: $f(0)>3$ is indeed sufficient, but f(0)>0 is no longer sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the last part of your reasoning is incorrect. We have $f(x)>f(0)-x$, and we want $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in[0,3]$.

A sufficient condition for $f(x)>0$ would be $f(0)-x>0$  (since we would then have $f(x)>f(0)-x>0$), or equivalently $f(0)>x$.

Since $x\in[0,3]$, thus $f(0)>x$ for all $x$ requires $f(0)>3$.

Comment: ah okk so the final condition could be : f(0)>3, right?

Comment: @axi: Yes, that's right